# Is there a User Interface for editing MSBuild Projects?

Tags: msbuild

I work in a dev environment where we heavily use MSBuild - I find myself constantly having to edit my build csproj xml by hand.  I hate this - there seems like there should be a nice UI for editing these files and performing common tasks.  I would of imagined that a tab in Project Properties Pages in Visual Studio would have given me something but alas.  Ideally I would be able to:

1. Do everything I can in Xml including being able to interact with any custom steps I created
2. See what the MSBuild variables evaluated to
3. See where the variables are defined so that I could quickly navigate to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out Attrice Corporations Microsoft Build Sidekick v2.3.  Here's the link: http://www.attrice.info/msbuild/

Version 1 is also available as freeware. Here's the link: http://www.attrice.info/msbuild/version1.htm

Comment: Version 1 appears to no longer be available for download.

Answer (score 6):

#### [MSBuild explorer](http://www.msbuildexplorer.com/)

[image: msbuild explorer]

*Some padding to make this 30 chars*

Comment: There is already a v3 which looks quite nice and is now hosted on github

Comment: seems this might be a dead project. the link now goes to a website which hands out serial keys for sims and other stuff. i searched google but couldnt find this project.

Answer (score 4):

Since I don't have funds for this MsBuild sidekick, I use [Msbuild Template](http://msbuildtemplate.codeplex.com/) in visual studio and [MsBuild Profiler](http://msbuildprofiler.codeplex.com/).

I have all my tasks split out in to multiple files and when I need to test / debug I run the single task from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

[Attrice Microsoft Build Sidekick](http://www.attrice.info/msbuild/) is the best I know.

Actually, I'm not quite sure if there are any other graphical tool for MSBuild.

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another one: [MSBuild Launcher](http://msbuildlauncher.codeplex.com/)

[image]